# Identity Server 4, Multiple instances of User Manager to same database, cannot login after Password reset

Tags: asp.net-core-identity

I have an instance of Identity server hosted and require a separate instance of the UserManger service to allow support teams to manage Users. I have created a helper method to expose functions of the UserManger, however once I do a password reset using this helper,  the User cannot login to the web application using the newly updated password.

Any Ideas would be Greatly Appreciated.

How I get the Instance of UserManager

```
 public ServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(string connectionString)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddLogging();

        if (connectionString.ToUpper() == "TEST")
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "MyTestDB" + new Guid().ToString());
                options.ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning));
            });
        }
        else
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        }

        //This method also does not work 
        //services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        //     .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        //    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => { });
        new IdentityBuilder(typeof(ApplicationUser), typeof(ApplicationRole), services)
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>()
            .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager()
    {
        var serviceProvider = CreateServiceProvider(_settings.SQLConnectionString);
        var scope = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();
        return scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

    }
```

Method I use to Set the Password for User:

```
  public async Task<bool> SetUserPasswordAsync(long User, string Password)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = await _UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.ToString());
        if (await _UserManager.HasPasswordAsync(user))
            await _UserManager.RemovePasswordAsync(user);

            var hashPwd = _UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(user, Password);
            await _UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(user, hashPwd);
            await _UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Using this same Usermanager to create a test user and then trying to login works perfectly, there seems to be something that I am missing to just set the new password for the User.

```
  var pleb = new ApplicationUser
 {
    UserName = "SomeGuy@somewhere.co",
    Email = "SomeGuy@somewhere.co",
    FirstName = "TestUser",
    LastName = "FOR This Usermanager"
  };
  await _UserManager.CreateAsync(pleb, "Password1!");
  await _UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(pleb, "Admin");
```

**UPDATE #2**
For some reason this works....

```
var user = await _UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.ToString());
var hashPwd = _UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(user, Password);
user.PasswordHash = hashPwd;
var result = await _UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are hashing the password and on insert it gets hashed again.

Instead of hashing the password, insert the text password. Translated to your code:

```
var result = await _userManager.AddPasswordAsync(User, Password);
```

I think you can suffice with this code:

```
public async Task<bool> SetUserPasswordAsync(long userId, string password)
{
    try
    {
        var user = await _UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId.ToString());
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (await _UserManager.HasPasswordAsync(user))
                await _UserManager.RemovePasswordAsync(user);

            var result = await _UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(user, password);
            return result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log message
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please note that the naming is very confusing. *User* is already known in the context. And since it's actually the *id* that is stored in the parameter, rather call it *userId*. Also note the casing.

---

There is one alternative that I've used, which may have the benefit of being one transaction. [Generate](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.generatepasswordresettokenasync) a password reset token as you would for a user initiated request, but instead of sending the token to the user, use it directly:

```
public async Task<bool> SetUserPasswordAsync(long userId, string password)
{
    try
    {
        var user = await _UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId.ToString());
        if (user != null)
        {
            IdentityResult result = null;

            if (await _UserManager.HasPasswordAsync(user))
            {
                var token = await _UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

                result = await _UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, password);
            }
            else
            {
                result = await _UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(user, password);
            }
            // Or you can return the result instead of whether it succeeded
            return result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log message
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I added code exactly as specified. When doing a user Password reset, it still refuses to login. on the web side.

Comment: What does SetUserPasswordAsync return? Is there an exception when executing AddPasswordAsync?

Comment: @JacquesBronkhorst Given your comments it seems that AddPasswordAsync fails. The reason is returned in 'result'. If you can share what the result is, then we may be able to answer your question.

Comment: `AddPasswordAsync` will fail if user already has password set up. OPs initial piece of code is correct in a sense that he needs to clear password out before setting it again.

Comment: To your point of generating a reset token. I believe, TOTP implementation (which you get with default EmailTokenProvider) will rely on user's SecurityStamp field - it will update the code each time you request a token. I will not claim to know exactly how TOTP works but I do suspect you will end up making more database roundtrips than if you just had removed and re-added a password as per your initial idea.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [`UserManager` source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/27314f478aac87f3fd09f94ccd9b83f738da6ab1/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L767) reveals, `AddPasswordAsync` **does not take hash**, but rather a **plaintext** password and [hashes it itself](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/27314f478aac87f3fd09f94ccd9b83f738da6ab1/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L767).

Before it does so, it by default fires off a `ValidatePasswordAsync` and does not proceed unless validation is successful. If everything is fine, the method calls `UpdatePasswordHash` and `UpdateUserAsync` (which means your second call is kinda pointless unless you do more changes). The confusion starts from the fact that most of the time, these functions do not throw exceptions, but rather return an `IdentityResult` that will have `.Succeeded` set to `false` - you have to handle it and let the caller know what went wrong.

Therefore you could rewrite your method like so to leverage off the behaviour above:

```
public async Task<bool> SetUserPasswordAsync(long User, string Password)
{
    try
    {
        var user = await _UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.ToString());
        if (await _UserManager.HasPasswordAsync(user))
            await _UserManager.RemovePasswordAsync(user);

        var result = await _UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(user, Password);
        if(!result.Succeeded)
        {
            var errors = result.Errors.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, e) => sb.AppendLine(e.Description)); // result.Errors is a List<IdentityError> so feel free to handle it as you see fit, I'm just grabbing all errors
            Console.WriteLine(errors);
        }
        return result.Succeeded;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Your updated example:

```
var user = await _UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.ToString());
var hashPwd = _UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(user, Password);
user.PasswordHash = hashPwd;
var result = await _UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

works because it basically bypasses all the built-in validations of `UserManager` and simply sets a value (which is probably not the best idea).

In your other example I suspect your new password fails complexity check but your code does not adequately report it back so it looks like it didn't work.

I see a couple of options if you absolutely must tinker with the logic:

1. Inherint from `UserManager` and override the methods you need - most of them are virtual so it should be relatively easy to do.
2. Clear your `_UserManager.PasswordValidators` list or define your own [`PasswordValidator`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordValidator.cs) and register it in `CreateServiceProvider` like so:

   ```
   services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
           .AddPasswordValidator<YourCustomValidator>()
   ```